# MakeUppercase capitalizes fontspec feature names

Tags: fontspec, textcase

The attached MWE does not work properly for `\MakeUppercase` alters `FakeSlant` to `FAKESLANT` prior to expanding `\addfontfeature`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Erewhon}
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{my  {\addfontfeature{FakeSlant=0.4}italic} is slanted!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you have a real use case for using such low level access `\addfontfeature{` mid document rather than setting up a slanted font in the preamble?  At least `\DeclareRobustCommand\zzz{\addfontfeature{FakeSlant=0.4}italic}}`  then use `\zzz`

Comment: No need indeed! I just got the example due to an error. However its a strange behavior.

Comment: It is the _expected_ behaviour, `\MakeUppercase` has no way of knowing that that is not text.